# Can someone explain the use of JTexPane in a GUI and if it affects the output of the program if not used correctly?

Tags: java

I am working on an assignment for my Java class and I wrote a code that works similar to Microsoft word's word counter.  Everything on my code works, the problem is when I run the program I need to click on the window in order for my output to appear or else nothing will show up.  It acts as if it is hidden.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //JPanel contentPane = null;
    //JTextField textField;
    int length;
    String msg; 

    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a sentence: ");
    msg = scan.nextLine();

    length = msg.length();

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Word Count");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setSize(400, 300);

    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Statistics");
    label1.setFont(new Font("Onyx", Font.BOLD, 12));
    label1.setBounds(30, 10, 135, 15);
    frame.add(label1);

    JButton ex = new JButton("Close");
    ex.setBounds(30, 200, 50, 50);
    ex.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        System.exit(0);
    }});

    frame.add(ex);
    frame.setVisible(true);


    JTextPane lbl = new JTextPane();
    lbl.setBounds(30, 30, 310, 150);
    lbl.setText(getStats(msg));
    frame.getContentPane().add(lbl);
    frame.setVisible(true);



}
public static String getStats(String msg){

    int spcCount = 0;
    int aCount = 0;
    String tmpMsg = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < msg.length(); i++){

        if(msg.charAt(i) == ' '){
            spcCount++;
        }else if(msg.charAt(i) == 'a'){
            aCount++;
        }
    }

        tmpMsg += "Characters (with spaces)\t\t" + msg.length() + "\n";
        tmpMsg += "Characters (without spaces)\t\t" + (msg.length()-spcCount) + "\n";
        tmpMsg += "Spaces\t\t\t\t" + spcCount + "\n";
        tmpMsg += "Words\t\t\t\t" + (spcCount+1) + "\n";
        tmpMsg += "Vowels\t\t\t\t" + (msg.length() - msg.toLowerCase().replaceAll("a|e|i|o|u", "").length()) + "\n";

        return tmpMsg;

    }
```

}

This problem is obviously annoying and not efficient.  So does the use of TextPane here cause this issue?  Thank you in advance and don't hesitate to make edits if it helps with wording the question better.

Comment: you have frame.setVisible(true); in there twice.  that might fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added few lines of code for setting it in front and deleted frame.setVisible(true); duplicate, main should look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //JPanel contentPane = null;
    //JTextField textField;
    int length;
    String msg;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a sentence: ");
    msg = scan.nextLine();

    length = msg.length();

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Word Count");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setSize(400, 300);

    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Statistics");
    label1.setFont(new Font("Onyx", Font.BOLD, 12));
    label1.setBounds(30, 10, 135, 15);

    JButton ex = new JButton("Close");
    ex.setBounds(30, 200, 50, 50);
    ex.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }

    });
    frame.add(label1);
    frame.add(ex);

    JTextPane lbl = new JTextPane();
    lbl.setBounds(30, 30, 310, 150);
    lbl.setText(getStats(msg));
    frame.getContentPane().add(lbl);

    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    frame.toFront();
    frame.requestFocus();
    frame.setAlwaysOnTop(false);

}
```

Comment: It looks like just adding frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true); fixes the issue.  What's with all the methods.

Comment: @FilipRistic Wow that fixed it straight away, Thanks a bunch!  I originally thought i needed that other setVisible in order for my close button to show.

Comment: @Nick I will try this now.

Comment: @nick Yes it also works, I did not see your comment earlier but it does work without adding the extra code. Thank you.

Comment: @NickZiebert Because then it will stay over other windows all the time, it works but it is not right way to do it.

Comment: @FilipRistic Oh, that's pretty nifty.  Cool.